# Can CRC mismatch cause error in connection with libnetcdff.so.6?

Tags: gdb, ubuntu-14.04, gfortran, crc, netcdf

When I run my Fortran code under Ubuntu 14.04 OS I get the following error:`error while loading shared libraries: libnetcdff.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. I saw the ld path with `ldd KiD_SC_2D.exe` but it seems that `libnetcdff` is found:

```
beata@beata-HP-Z420-Workstation:~/Downloads/kid_a_setup/bin$ ldd KiD_SC_2D.exe
  linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd83a4000)
  libnetcdff.so.6 => /home/beata/netcdf/lib/libnetcdff.so.6 (0x00007f3849432000)
  libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007f3849101000)
  libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3848dfa000)
  libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3848be4000)
  libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f384881f000)
  libnetcdf.so.7 => /home/beata/netcdf/lib/libnetcdf.so.7 (0x00007f3848533000)
  libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f38482f7000)
  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3849694000)
```

When I had run `gdb` I got the following warning:

```
warning: the debug information found in "/lib64/ld-2.19.so" does not match "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" (CRC mismatch)
```

Is it possible that this warning causes the matter of  `libnetcdff.so.6`? As so how I can fix this CRC mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that this warning causes the matter of libnetcdff.so.6?

No, it's entirely unrelated.

> As so how I can fix this CRC mismatch?

The mismatch says that the installed version of `libc6` and `libc6-dbg` packages do not match. Update `libc6-dbg` to match installed `libc6`, and the warning should go away.

As for why `libnetcdff.so.6` is not found, you are not telling us the whole story. Clearly `ldd` does find it, and running `KiD_SC_2D.exe` should as well. To debug this, you may wish to run it like so:

```
cd ~/Downloads/kid_a_setup/bin
env LD_DEBUG=files,libs ./KiD_SC_2D.exe
```

That should tell you where the dynamic linker is looking for `libnetcdff`.

Comment: I ran `LD_DEBUG=files,libs KiD_SC_2D.exe` but it did not give information about `libnetcdff.so.6`. But it wrote  : `
 25485: opening file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis.so.2 [0]; direct_opencount=1
     25485: 
KiD_SC_2D.exe: command not found` I do not know why and what I should to do?